# iPhone issue when executing in standalone mode

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, fft

I googled during a lot of time my problem and I didn't find anything helpful so I hope one of you will be able to help me.

I developed an iPhone application which process FFT on audio input frames using the FFTS implementation ( https://github.com/anthonix/ffts ).

When I run my application in my iPhone 5 using xCode, all goes well, but, when I run it in a standalone mode (it means I click on the app icon in the iPhone and not on the xCode launcher) the application starts but crashs as soon as an FFTS instruction is called.

The stacktrace in the crash report is :

```
0   libsystem_c.dylib           0x3b163eb0 sys_icache_invalidate + 8
1   FFTApp                      0x002f6b80 ffts_generate_func_code + 6252
2   FFTApp                      0x002f4094 ffts_init_1d + 2084
3   FFTApp                      0x002cab86 APFFTProcessor::APFFTProcessor(int) (APFFTProcessor.cpp:49)
```

When I switch the FFT implementation and used vDSP instead of FFTS, all goes well via xCode and via the standalone mode.

I really don't have any idea about why this issue happens but if someone is able to help me it will be appreciate :-)

Thank you for your attention, have a great day!

Sébastien.

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like your FFTS library generates code dynamically and you're crashing when it tries to invalidate the instruction cache.  I suggest you stick with vDSP - it's much more future-proof anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul ! You were right, it seems that the FFTS library has an option --disable-dynamic-code, it is really weird that using xCode all went well, but now I added this option and it past successfully :-)

Comment: It may well be something that works OK on the simulator but not on an actual device.

Comment: I never ran it with the simulator, only on the iPhone one time via xCode wich put all the necessary stuff on the device and launch the application on the device, and one time, I click directly on the application installed on the device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sandboxed app on a stock OS iPhone can't run dynamically generated ARM code.  The iOS memory permissions don't allow it.  But the Xcode-assisted debugger does, so that it can insert breakpoints, etc.